# What constitutes a valid URI query parameter key?

Tags: ruby, validation, uri

I'm looking over [Section 3.4 of RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) trying to understand what constitutes a valid URI query parameter key, but I'm not seeing a clear answer.

The reason I'm asking is because I'm writing a [Ruby class that composes a URI with query parameters](https://github.com/ryanburnette/compose_url). When a new parameter is added I want to validate the key. Based on experience, it seems like the key will be invalid if it requires any escaping.

I should also say that I plan to validate the key. I'm not sure how to go about validating this data either, but I do know that in all cases I should escape this value.

Advice is appreciated. Advice in the context of how validation might already be possible through say a Ruby Gem would also be a plus.

Comment: Why not use existing classes? Ruby's built-in [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) or the [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) gem should do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you referring to the validation question or regarding my ComposeURL class?

Comment: I assume the latter. I find working with my [ComposeURL](https://github.com/ryanburnette/compose_url) class a ton quicker and easier that working directly with URI. URI is a dependency though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could well be wrong, but that spec seems to say that anything following '?' or '#' is valid as long.  I wonder if you should be looking more at the spec for 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' (ie. the key/value pairs we're all used to)?

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1

> This is the default content type. Forms submitted with this content
> type must be encoded as follows:
>
> Control names and values are escaped. Space characters are replaced by `+', and then reserved characters are escaped as described in [RFC1738], section 2.2: Non-alphanumeric characters are replaced by` %HH', a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing the ASCII code of the character. Line breaks are represented as "CR LF" pairs (i.e., `%0D%0A').
>
> The control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document. The name is separated from the value by `=' and name/value pairs are separated from each other by` &'.

Comment: What's technically valid in a URI is pretty open-ended, a URI can be used for a lot more than HTTP. What's valid in the form-encoding is much more limited, so you're right to focus there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `key=value` is part of the RFC, it's a convention that has emerged.  [Wikipedia suggests](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#form-content-type) this is an 'W3C recommendation'.

Seems like some good stuff to be found searching on the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#form-data-set